# Delete button placement?

Tags: buttons, data-tables

I am currently working on an application that allows for massive data entry. With that data entry also come with a need to delete some of the entries.

The flow of the application starts when a user goes to a screen that lists all the entries. (This list will display the name and phone number of the entry.) They have the option of adding a new entry to the list or clicking on the entry to get more information.

When clicked, the user gets presented a screen that displays more information regarding that data entry. At the moment that screen shows a two tab system and in the content there are two tables of data. At this point the user may want to delete this entry, because it is out of date or for some other reason.

My problem is that no place on the screen makes sense for the button to be located and I was wondering if someone could help me out and give me some advice.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to provide a wireframe or screenshot of the screen?

Comment: Wireframe, Sketch or Screenshot please. :-)

Comment: Sorry about that thought I placed an image on there..must have forgot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I've understood you correct - but if you want to delete individual entries - you could add links (or buttons) to edit or delete items. If you feel you need confirmation on deletes, you could also use a confirmation popup following the delete-click.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxnLza.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

But if you want to delete more than one item at a time - you could use the checkbox delete actions implemented on Outlook.com mail or GMail:

[image]

Check the items you want to delete or all items checkbox - and hit delete.